# SUM operation in a single formula Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to make one formula that calculates:
`SUM[ Qi * (P1i - P2i), i=1 to n]`

Example:

```
 Q           X               P1     P2
 100         2,261.00    22.61  22.59
 19,600      200,151.39      10.21  10.18
 10,700      800,008.00      74.77  74.84
```

[100 * (22.61 - 22.59 )] + [19,699 * (10.21 - 10.18)] + ....

I can do an workaround adding one column with my first calculation and then SUM the column. But i'm just curious if i could do this different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a `SUMPRODUCT` (assuming your data starts in `A2`):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A4,(C2:C4-D2:D4))
```

And extend the `4` to the boundary you want.